# Is it possible to use #if #endif statement in Asp.NET MVC .cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

What I want to do is, set a variable as "Scheduler/Get" if the mode is Debug and "GI/Scheduler/Get" if the mode is Release.

I know that in C# code, I should do something like this:

```
string x = "";

#if DEBUG
  x = "Scheduler/Get";
#else
  x = "GI/Scheduler/Get";
#endif
```

The problem is that I want to do it in a javascript method inside my view. Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: What's your issue?  Yes that's possible.  Probably be cleaner to chuck in a helper

Comment: That issue is exactly what I wrote. I want to write something if the program is in debug mode and other thing if it is in realease mode. But inside a javascript method in my view.

Comment: Why can't you do what I said? Make a helper method to return whether your on debut mode and just use that conditionally to write JavaScript in a '<script>' tag

Comment: Because I didn't understand what you said. Can you please give me an example? I'm a little bit confused. Thank you

Comment: I cannot give you an example because your question is already marked duplicate. But the answer is written in the duplicate question